# SDL.NET vs SDL C++

Tags: c++, sdl, .net

I am currently transitioning from XNA to SDL, and was wondering if SDL.NET provides the same benefits as SDL C++.

Considering that SDL.NET uses the .NET framework as a wrapper to the SDL base libraries, I would assume that this creates less portable code.

If I want to be able to compile my source to multiple platforms, would it be best for me to stick with C++ ?  Or will SDL.NET provide the same benefits?

Comment: As far as I know, .NET framework is only available on Windows.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to work with Mono. It's cross-platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET Framework is availble on other operating systems if you use Mono. If your problems are just about cross-platformness, I would highly suggest you use MonoDevelop.

However, it seems SDL.NET has some issues with Mono, at least on Android.

I suggest you do some research about SDL.NET and Mono and see if would be OK to use this match-up.

Comment: Yes, upon reading some more, SDL.NET doesn't seem to be a very good solution for the time being (for me).